# help with trying to prove why having two sides and any angle is insufficent proof for congruence.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

t The author challenges the reader to prove why two sides and any angle is insufficent proof by constructing two triangles with two 1 cm sides and one 45 degree angle. I tried to prove this using the sine rule setting it out how the author proves the other theorem e.g. equating two equations for c and showing that since they equal 0 c=c and so all the sides in the triangle are the same thus the angles are the same so the triangles are congruent. 
[image: Here is a picture from the book]

> Here is how i tried to prove it a=1 b=1 and c is unknown.
>   sinA=45
>
> so (1/sin45)=(1/sinb)=(c/sinc)
>
> (sinb/sin45-1)=(c/sinc)
>
> ((sinc)(sina)/(sin45))-1=c
>   ?
>
> since there are two equal triangles c=c
>
> ((sinc)(sina)/(sin45))-1=((sinc)(sina)/(sin45))-1

solving this gives 0 which means that c is equal to c meaning that the triangles are congruent. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The algebraic passages you do are not very clear. Could you try and improve them?

Comment: It would help you and the readers to use $B$ and $C$ for the angles, not the same letters as the lengths $b$ and $c$.

Answer (score 3):

Given the green side, the red side, and the blue angle, there are two triangles possible:

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

---

It has been pointed out that the example in the book is for two sides of $1$ and an angle of $45^\circ$. Unfortunately with those values, the family of examples I tried to illustrate above won't work. Below is what I guess they must be going for, although I don't think this is a good counterexample since you are usually given what side the angle opposes.

$\hspace{8mm}$[image]

Comment: Could you explain the diagram please?

Comment: @IntentFilters: You are given the length of a green side, the length of a red side, and the angle opposite the red side. As shown, there can be two triangles made with these sides and angle.

Comment: how would this prove that the angles are not congruent?

Comment: @robjohn: The OP is given that the triangle is isosceles, with at least one angle measuring $45^\circ.$ This isn't about the ambiguous case of SSA. Rather, it is pointing out that given two sides and *some* angle (included or otherwise), we cannot necessarily determine the congruence class of the triangle, unless the given angle happens to be right.

Comment: @CameronBuie: that seems a bad example for this since usually you are given which side the angle opposes. Oh, well.

Comment: As clear as possible. +1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Try an isosceles right triangle and another (non-right) isosceles triangle.

Comment: Thanks to this and maths loves answer i think i understand now.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it! I would point out that Peter's (now deleted) answer and robjohn's answer were based on a (very understandable) misreading. A common question is about the ambiguous case of an SSA triangle--that is, two sides and a non-included angle. The picture in robjohn's post illustrates the ambiguity perfectly (and clearly two upvoters who also misread the question agree).

Answer (score 0):

Note that your example has $CA=CB=1, \angle CAB=\angle CBA=45^\circ$ .

We can constract distinct triangle $ABC$ such as the following :

$AB=AC=1, \angle BAC=45^\circ.$

Comment: So if i understand this right since i havent done the algebra yet. Since the angles are in different places, im guessing the algebra wont work out to 0 meaning that the two sides are not equal?

Comment: I don't think the algebra won't work, but in this case drawing figures is just simple.

Comment: Do you mean literally drawing out to scale diagrams?

Comment: Yes. In my opinion, this kind of questions needs both calculation and drawing figures. In other words, doing calculation with drawing the figures in order to see what the situation is.