# Triangle congruence when the longest sides, the largest angles, and one of the other sides are congruent?

Tags: geometry, triangles, congruences-geometry

Are two [scalene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#By_lengths_of_sides) triangles (a scalene triangle is one with no two equal
sides) congruent if their longest sides, largest angles, and shortest sides are congruent?

I believe the case described above is a special case of
side-side-angle that actually implies congruence of the two triangles
involved.  Please let me know if you can come up with any
counterexample, that is, two triangles that are not congruent and
satisfy the conditions described above.  I couldn't come up with such an example.

Here is a [counterexample](https://mathopenref.com/congruentssa.html), not for the problem above, but for the
general side-side-angle case where shows side-side-angle in general
is not a sufficient condition for congruence of two triangles.

Here is a [close answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/616527/568655) on StackExchange, but it still doesn't answer my question.

**Here is my attempt to solve the problem---side-side-angle special case**

We want to prove that given the largest and the smallest sides of a
triangle along with the measure of its largest angle, we can construct
one and only one such triangle.

The largest angle ought to be opposite the longest side.  Thus, the
shortest side shall be adjacent to the largest angle.

We start to construct the triangle by drawing the shortest side AB.
Then we draw the ray AC such that the angle BAC becomes the largest
angle in the triangle.  Note that the angle BAC can be a right,
obtuse, or acute angle without violating the assumption that the side
BC is the largest side (See figure parts a, b, and c).

(an interesting but irrelevant question may be "What is the smallest
possible measure of the largest angle in an scalene triangle given the
size of its largest and smallest sides?"---can be solved using the sine rule)

Now we take the last step in constructing the triangle by drawing an
arc centered at B with a radius $r$ which equals the length of the
longest side BC.  Then, we claim that we can uniquely find the third
vertex C of the triangle where the arc intersects the ray AC.

The arc shall not intersect the ray AC in more than one point because that would require the arc to intersect the side AB as well which implies that the side AB is longer than the side BC which contradicts our assumption.  Thus, the point C is unique.

[image: side-side-angle special case]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an argument for the uniqueness of C, we can use sine rule. With your notation,
$$\frac{\sin|\angle ACB|}{|AB|}=\frac{\sin|\angle BAC|}{BC}$$
As $AB$ is the shortest side, it is opposite the smallest angle. In particular, we must have that $ACB$ is acute, so sine rule uniquely determines it. So we can then determine all the angles, and all the sides.

Your construction can produce two choices for C if $|\angle BAC|\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. But one of the points will give $|AB|\geq |AC|$, so won't give the prescribed triangle.

Comment: @Adrian why $\angle ACB$ must be acute?

Comment: $\angle ACB$ is opposite the shortest side $AB$, so it is the smallest angle. If it were greater than 90 degrees, then $\angle ABC\geq 90$ and $\angle BAC \geq 90$, so $180=\angle ACB + \angle ABC + \angle BAC \geq 270$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score -1):

The criterion you provided -

- longest side
- largest angle
- any other side

That is more than enough, all we need to know is that either the angle given is the largest or that the side given is the largest.

[image: The image explains why ASS doesn't work.]

Given

- AB
- $\angle$BAD(BAC)
- Side BD or BC

Side BC/BD intersects the rest of the triangle at two distinct points

$\angle$BDC = $\angle$BCD
$\implies$
BCA + BDC = 180$\circ$
$\implies$

- $\angle$BCA is obtuse

  or $\angle$BDA is obtuse

  or $\angle$BCA = $\angle$BDA = 90 $\circ$

When the angle we are given is the largest, the angle can't be obtuse therefore we can narrow down our triangle to one possible case.

When we are given the largest side,

- if the side does not share a vertex with a given angle (BD or BC)
  then $\angle$ A is the largest angle and the other angles cannot be obtuse.
- if however we are given that side AB is the longest then we cannot prove congruency.

Comment: I don't quite see what you're saying.  If you mean only two of the three conditions in the question title is enough to prove the congruence of two triangles, then that's definitely not true.  For example, suppose the largest angles and the largest sides of two triangles are congruent.  Then the two triangles need not be congruent...

Comment: ... You can create infinitely many such incongruent triangles by putting the needle point of a pair of compasses on one ray of an obtuse angle to draw an arc that intersects the other ray of the angle.  That gives you one triangle.  Then if you take the needle and put it on a different point on one ray to draw another arc intersecting the other ray at the same radius, you will have another triangle.  These two triangles will be incongruent although their largest angles and largest sides are congruent.

Comment: Infinitely many? Even just given a side and angle and an angle, we can create only two triangles .

Comment: I apologise for the confusion, i clarified it in the end of the post where it works only in some cases, what I mean is that we should be given one angle, and two sides. And on top of that we need only one additional fact, such as a side being the longest or an angle being the largest.

Comment: @GeneralASWlater I still do not understand what you mean in your answer and in your comment.  All of what you wrote and drew, from the very beginning till the end, needs to be heavily edited until I begin to understand your assumptions, your claims, your arguments, and your question ('infinitely many?') as well as its relevance to my precise question and comments.  Please be clear and precise and don't leave the reader guess what you mean.  In this case it's impossible for me to guess what you mean.

Comment: Your last comment, but not your answer, helped me understand what you mean: "we should be given one angle, and two sides. And on top of that we need only one additional fact, such as a side being the longest or an angle being the largest."  I found a counter example for the case of two incongruent triangles each having one congruent angle and two congruent sides where one of the sides is the largest.  So as you mentioned in the end of your answer, that case is not enough to prove congruence.  I think now your answer is correct, but still not clear.